# Drupal tagadelic how to limit tags shown

Tags: templates, drupal, tags, limit

I'm trying to limit somehow the tags shown by the tagadelic module.
I'm publishing it on a normal block, but I can't seem to make it limit the items shown...
can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It has some configuration parameters that you can access in admin-settings, like "number of tags" and "number of levels". Did you try these?
You can also try another module, like [Views Cloud](http://drupal.org/project/views_cloud).

Comment: yes I did but it doesn't work so well, it makes changes but if I put 10 it will show more than 10 ..never the right value.

Comment: I have modified the module directly the default value was 25 , in $options['size']=10; file theme.inc, and now it works..